# .eof() is not working in turbo c++

Tags: c++

`myfile.eof()` is not working in `turbo c++`.
Here is my fragment:

```
    while(viofile  >> vio.studnumb >> vio.firstname >> vio.lastname >> vio.code >> vio.remarks >> vio.date >> '/`enter code here`' >> vio.month >> '/'>>vio.year >> "Noted by:" >> vio.filler >> vio.position >> vio.user)
   {
       if(vio.studnumb==studno)
       {
            cout << endl << studno << ' ' << vio.firstname << ' ' << vio.lastname << ' '<< endl;
            cout << "Violation :" << vio.code << ' ' << vio.remarks << ' ' << vio.date << '/' << vio.month<< '/' << vio.year <<endl;
            cout << "   Noted by: " << vio.positio`enter code here`n << ' ';
            cout <<vio.user;
    break;
   }
   else if(viofile.eof())
    cout << "You have no violation.\n";
   }
```

I have a project to finish. Please reply.

thank you.

Comment: Please tell me this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

If any call to `operator>>` reaches end of file, `eofbit` will be set and the stream will convert to false in boolean context. At which point the program will drop out of the loop. If the execution made it into the loop, then `(bool)viofile` is still true, and so `viofile.eof()` can't possibly return true.

Use a boolean flag - set it to false before the loop, set it to true when you print a violation. After the loop, if this flag still isn't set, then you haven't printed and violations, which you can report accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read into a string literal, i.e.,

```
std::cin >> "<some string>"
```

is illegal. If you need to decode a corresponding string, you'll need to create a suitable parsing routine.

Since you only read one set of inputs before breaking out of the loop, I'd guess I would check that not failure occurred, though, as there is no need to have reached the end of file at the point, i.e., I would use

```
if (in) {
    ...
}
```

Given that input generally stops when a space character, e.g., a newline is encountered, you would need to skip, at least, trailing whitespaces to hope that the end of the file was reached:

```
if ((in >> std::ws).eof()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: "a while-loop doesn't have an else branch" -- I think this is just an artifact of broken indentation, the `else` applies to `if(vio.studnumb==studno)`.

Comment: Shame actually that `std::cin >> "skip this" >> foo` doesn't work. `scanf` does work that way. C++ really could use a decent input mechanism, `<istream>` makes simple things way too hard and hard things virtually impossible.

Comment: @MSalters: To some level I do agree with this assessment. However, when I experimented with matching characters when reading a string literal I found that it is rather error-prone: it is very easy to accidentally end up with a non-`const` C-string where the parsing would require a `const` C-string. ... and there is already an overload reading into a non-`const` C-string (which easily becomes the C++ version of `gets()` if the `width()` isn't set up). If I spot a question how to make something like this work using streams I'm happy to post an approach to implement simple matching of a string.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You are right. I'm just too much of a pattern matcher for source code! With badly formatted code people could probably get all sort of junk past my code reviews.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: the fix for that is to auto-indent the code you're reviewing, diff the result against the original, and reject if they're too different ;-)